# ERROR: block is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler

Tags: task, block, ansible

I have a simple block test playbook but i keep getting the error trying to execute it.

```
    ---
- hosts: webservers
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name:  this is a test
          debug: msg="blabla"
      when: ansible_fqdn.split('.')[1]=='dev'
```

Not sure at the moment what is causing this... please help!

Comment: What is your ansible version? (`ansible --version`)?

[Blocks were only added in 2.0](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html).

Comment: thank you for reply: ansible 1.9.4
  configured module search path = None

Comment: There you go then. Upgrade to Ansible 2 if you need block functionality.

Comment: thank you very much. that did it. installed ansible 2.0.1 from epel now i have a slew of new issues

Answer (score 3):

As @ydaetskcoR pointed out, you need to install Ansible 2.0 to use blocks.

Repeating this here so there can be an accepted answer.